# Highcharts : synchronized charts, It's possible export download image all in one?

Tags: highcharts

As you can see the demo is 3 in 1 chart.

I can download it separately by navigation menu.
But that's not what I expected.

It's possible export download image all in one?

#### Code

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
navigation: {
    buttonOptions: {
        align: 'center'
    }
}
```

#### Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/puff0211/r43w7qne/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged the fiddle from your answer with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/gd7bB/

**Final effect** seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/pzfhnpjh/

The only modification that I did was moving `width` definition for every chart from CSS (for some reason it doesn't work when defined there):

```
.chart {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*height: 220px;*/
}
```

to chart options in JS:

```
chart: {
    marginLeft: 40, // Keep all charts left aligned
    spacingTop: 20,
    spacingBottom: 20,
    height: 220 // added
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library to capture your web page (or a portion of it) and transform to a Canvas, so it can be saved as a picture:

```
html2canvas($("#container"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(), 'download.png');
  }
});
```

If you want, using [jsPdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), the Canvas can be saved also as PDF.

```
html2canvas($("#container"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
    doc.save('download.pdf');
  }
});
```

Check this fiddle (update from yours): http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/saku390u/

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer Highcharts solution.

Comment: Yes, it's a better solution. Vote up for that answer.